# Analysis of the eigenvalues doesn't tell anything about the stability of fixed points?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the equation for the bead on a rotating without friction:
$$\frac{d^2 \phi}{dt^2}= -\frac{g}{r}\sin\phi + \omega^2 \sin\phi \cos\phi,$$

What does analysis of the eigenvalues of the Jacobi matrix tell you about the stability of the fixed point $(\phi=0,\frac{d\phi}{dt} = 0)?$

**My attempt:**
Let $\frac{d\phi}{dt} = \psi$, then the original equation can be rewritten as system of first-order equation:$

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{d\psi}{dt}= -\frac{g}{r}\sin\phi + \omega^2 \sin\phi \cos\phi \\
\frac{d\phi}{dt} = \psi
\end{cases}$$

Then the fixed points are $(\phi^*, \psi^*)=(\pi k,0).$ Next, we linearize to determine the stability of the fixed points. The Jacobi matrix near $(0,0)$ is

$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -\frac{g}{r}+\omega^2 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

The eigenvalues of this matrix has 0 real part.

I'm stuck here, how do we determine the stability of the point $(0,0)$?

Comment: This is a conservative system (Hamiltonian, even), so you should expect the Jacobian to tell you nothing about stability. But the level curves of the Hamiltonian function (= the conserved energy) should tell you something instead.